# Code navigation utility

Tags: windows

Is there any tool in windows that navigates through the code and identifies functions/function trees that are unreferenced?

Regards,
Dejavu

Comment: Such a tool would have to be language specific.  Which language is of interest?

Comment: If you want to check Java, just use eclipse. Every unreferenced entity is marked with a warning. You can do a lot more of checks with eclipse, just activate them in the program settings and there Java - Compiler - Errors/Warnings